# Add space between two columns in datatables

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

My goal is to rewrite some of our old html tables using DataTable so that we can use their abilities (filtering, etc...)

I would like to have a unique table shown like two separate tables, juste like in example below :

[image]

I need it to be one unique table so that scrolling works on the two parts.

What was made before was adding an empty column and style it so that it looks like spacing, but I don't know what style I could use to have borders on header and at the bottom of my table, so that it's not showing on the empty column.

[image]

Can someone help me please ?
Thanks

---

UPDATE : my table is simply html based.

Here is my datatable instanciation :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        dom: '<t>',
        paging: false,
      scrollY: '200px',
      ordering: false,
      columns: [
        null, null, null, null, {className: "emptySpace"}, null, null
      ]
    });
});
```

Here is my css stylesheet :

```
.dataTables_scroll {
    clear: both;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.dataTables_scrollHeadInner {
    background-color: #afc99a;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border-top: 1px solid !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid !important;
}

th.emptySpace, td.emptySpace {
    background-color: white !important;
    border-bottom:none !important;
    border-top: none !important;
}

.table th, .table td  {
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-top: none;
}

tr.even td {
  background: #ecece9 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

And a JSFiddle example with an example code but my real css stylesheet :

https://jsfiddle.net/44p919fj/18/

I can't remove some borders...

Comment: could you please share your code?

Comment: I added my code and a jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "columnDefs":[
            {"sortable":false, "class":"spacer", "targets": 4}
    ]
});
```

With this CSS:

```
.spacer{
    background-color:white;
    border-top:none !important;
    border-bottom:none !important;
}
```

Though borders for left and right will be up to you to sort out. Basically what you suggested but "hide" the fact that you've got a blank row. Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/4cjjx2hd/1/).

You could even give the row before a thick white [border](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/4cjjx2hd/2/)...?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem is with scrolling : I still can't remove some borders. You can find an update with a jsfiddle example in my question. Thanks again !